# Finding the list of people who have birthday this week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to list the people who have birthday this week with this code:

```
declare @START_DATE date;
set @START_DATE  = DATEADD(dd, 1 - DATEPART(dw, getdate()), getdate())
declare @END_DATE date;
set @END_DATE = DATEADD(dd,6, @START_DATE)
set DATEFIRST 1

SELECT  @START_DATE as StartDate, Personel.DogumTarihi , @END_DATE as EndDate
      ,[Adi]
      ,[Soyadi]
      ,[BirimAdi]
      ,[DogumTarihi]
      ,[MudurlukAdi]
      ,[Gorevi]
      ,[CepTelefonu]
      ,[EvTelefonu]
from Personel 
where (
      DATEPART(m, Personel.DogumTarihi) = DATEPART(m, @START_DATE) 
  and DATEPART(DAY, Personel.DogumTarihi) >= DATEPART(DAY, @START_DATE) 
  and DATEPART(DAY, Personel.DogumTarihi) <= DATEPART(DAY, @END_DATE)
  ) 
  OR (
      DATEPART(m, Personel.DogumTarihi) = (DATEPART(m, @START_DATE)+ 1) 
  and DATEPART(DAY, Personel.DogumTarihi) <= DATEPART(DAY, @END_DATE)
  )
```

First I set the start date and calculate the end date according to start date. Then I set Monday as the first day of week. 
But everytime I run this, I receive a different Start date. I am quite new to Ms Sql Scripting, I may be doing sth wrong in the declarations but I couldn'd find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getdate()` also returns a time part. This will throw off your calculations. Also this will fail if the week-start is at the end of the month and the birthday is the same week but different month.

Comment: so what should I use instead? now()? For the second question I have developed a solution and added as answer below. It seems to work, but I don't know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())/7, 0) FirstDayOfCurrentWeek, 
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, DogumTarihi, GETDATE()), [DogumTarihi]) BirthdayThisYear,
        DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())/7, 0)) FirstDayOfNextWeek           
          ,[Adi]
          ,[Soyadi]
          ,[DogumTarihi]
          ,[BirimAdi]
          ,[MudurlukAdi]
          ,[Gorevi]
          ,[CepTelefonu]
          ,[EvTelefonu]         
FROM    Personel
WHERE   DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, [DogumTarihi], GETDATE()), [DogumTarihi]) >= DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())/7, 0)
        AND
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, [DogumTarihi], GETDATE()), [DogumTarihi]) < DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())/7, 0))
```

Comment: first thanks for answering. your code has the same issue with the one below. if the start and end date of the week are in different months (like this month) the query will not work correctly

Comment: @lamostreta Sorry, I fixed it, you can try it now

Comment: my method appeared to be not working properly. So I used your method, which works great. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help. I tested it for the borderline case when week spans across the end of the current and the beginning of the next year, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

ok, one more attempt:

```
where

case when year(@START_DATE) = year(@END_DATE) THEN '1' ELSE CASE WHEN month(@birthdate) = 12 THEN '0' WHEN month(@birthdate) = 1 THEN '1' ELSE '9' END END
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(@birthdate)),2)
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DAY(@birthdate)),2)

between

case when year(@START_DATE) = year(@END_DATE) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(@START_DATE)),2)
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DAY(@START_DATE)),2)

and

'1'
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(@END_DATE)),2)
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DAY(@END_DATE)),2)
```

Comment: Also, move your "SET DATEFIRST 1" statement to the top of your code.

Comment: If you have '1980.06.26' as Dogumgunu you can not see it in the result because the year is not the same.

Comment: I guess "DogumTarihi" is "birthday", which could be any year while START_DATE and END_DATE are the current year. So you need to check just day and month, and ignore year.

Comment: but this time if the start and end date of the week are in different months (like this month) the query will not work correctly.

Comment: sorry, yes DogumTarihi is birthday.. I also added "SET DATEFIRST 1" statement to the top of my code, and it worked in fixing the START_DATE.

Answer (score 1):

sql should let you specify the week directly

```
DATEPART(ww,GETDATE())
```

or in oracle:  `to_char( mydate, 'ww' )`

Comment: yes but 18th of March in 1980 may not have the same week count with a 18th of March in in 2012

Answer (score 1):

In order to cope with the my problem I revised the code above according to answers:

```
set DATEFIRST 1
declare @START_DATE date;
set @START_DATE  = DATEADD(dd, 1 - DATEPART(dw, getdate()), getdate())
declare @END_DATE date;
set @END_DATE = DATEADD(dd,6, @START_DATE)


SELECT  @START_DATE as StartDate, 

(case when 
(DATEPART(m, @START_DATE) = DATEPART(m, @END_DATE))
then 
(case when (DATEPART(DAY, Personel.DogumTarihi) >= DATEPART(DAY, @START_DATE) and DATEPART(DAY, Personel.DogumTarihi) <= DATEPART(DAY, @END_DATE)) then Personel.DogumTarihi else 0 end)
else 
    (case when DATEPART(m, Personel.DogumTarihi) = DATEPART(m, @START_DATE)
        then
            (case when (DATEPART(DAY, Personel.DogumTarihi) >= DATEPART(DAY, @START_DATE)) then Personel.DogumTarihi else 0 end)
        else
            (case when (DATEPART(DAY, Personel.DogumTarihi) <= DATEPART(DAY, @END_DATE)) then Personel.DogumTarihi else 0 end)
        end
    )
end), 
@END_DATE as EndDate, [TCKN]
      ,[Adi]
      ,[Soyadi]
      ,[BirimAdi]
      ,[DogumTarihi]
      ,[MudurlukAdi]
      ,[Gorevi]
      ,[CepTelefonu]
      ,[EvTelefonu]
      ,[VakifTelefonu]
from Personel where 
DATEPART(m, @START_DATE) = DATEPART(m, @END_DATE)
OR DATEPART(m, Personel.DogumTarihi) = DATEPART(m, @START_DATE)
OR DATEPART(m, Personel.DogumTarihi) = DATEPART(m, @END_DATE)
```

Now it is taking the case where "the start and end date of the month are in the same week (like this week)" into account. It looks like it is bringing right results..

Comment: pls see my last answer. it compares the birthday using a between, converting the 3 dates into strings like '00101' (being 1 jan, with the first 0 fixing the issue with weeks spanning 2 different years. i think it works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a try:

```
declare @today datetime

set @today = getdate()
-- erase the hours
set @today = dateadd(hh, -datepart(hh, @today), @today)
-- erase the minutes
set @today = dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, @today), @today)
-- erase the seconds    
set @today = dateadd(ss, -datepart(ss, @today), @today)
-- erase the milliseconds    
set @today = dateadd(ms, -datepart(ms, @today), @today)

-- go to start of current week (sunday!)    
set @today = dateadd(dd, 1-datepart(dw, @today), @today)

select * from MYTABLE
where DATECOL between 
  dateadd(yy, datepart(yy, DATECOL) - datepart(yy, @today), @today) and 
  dateadd(d, 7, dateadd(yy, datepart(yy, DATECOL) - datepart(yy, @today), @today))
```

Apparently SqlServer 2012 has a DATEFROMPARTS function, in 2005 we will have to use this roundabout way to trim a date.

To select a birthday, I exchange the "today's year" for the record's year. For the end-date of the range I add 7 days to that. Note that you want to search from sunday 0:00 to saturday 23:59.

This will probably still fail if halfway during the week a new year starts and the birthday you want is in the new year.